# Remove standard error message for check table in ALV grid

Tags: abap, alv

I'm using editable OO ALV to display some records from custom table. The key is `matnr` in ref table is `MARA`. User can insert new records or edit existing records. I need to check if `matnr` exists in `MARA`, if doesn't display err message. But because the `fieldacatolog` has ref table if user insert not valid `matnr`, pop up message is displayed with error message. I want to remove this message and to display other custom message. I can't delete ref table in the `fieldacatalog`, because it's needed for search help. Also my err message is

```
MESSAGE ID '00' TYPE 'S' NUMBER 058 WITH matnr '' '' 'MARA'  DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
```

Comment: Which ALV class are you using exactly?

Comment: Give your code of ALV initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Popup up messages and the message you want to show are two different things, so you can disable the popup up messages and just display your own.

After creating your alv grid object, just use this function to disable the popup one:

```
go_your_alv_grid_object->activate_display_protocol( space ).
```

To enable it again, use this:

```
go_your_alv_grid_object->activate_display_protocol( 'X' ).
```